# How to select values from 2 hours ago from now

Tags: mysql

I am not having much knowledge on mysql queries.. and i'm trying to get values from database from last two hours from now ..I have searched about it and i have found some related posts too.. but unfortunately i am unable to implement the logic.. please help me solve this issue..

here is the mysql query

```
select * 
from `ordermaster` 
where ((
`ordermaster`.`Pick_date`
 = curdate())
 and (`ordermaster`.`Pick_time`
 <= (now() - interval 2 hour)) 
and (`ordermaster`.`Status` 
= 2))
```

were, Pick_Date  = "2017-04-19" (today date) and Pick_Time =  "10:00:00" (24 hours format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `between` keyword

```
select  *
from    `ordermaster` 
where   `Pick_date` = curdate() and
        `Pick_time` between (now() - interval 2 hour) and now() and
        `Status` = 2
```

**Edit**

Based on our chat, where we found out the GoDaddy server you have your db hosted on is 12.5 hours ahead of your local time, the final query you should use is

```
select  *
from    `ordermaster` 
where   `Pick_date` = curdate() and
        `Pick_time` <= now() + interval 10 hour + interval 30 minute and
        `Status` = 2
```

Comment: hi stefano.. thanks for replying.. I tried your solution but not getting the result.. as i mentioned the pick_time = 10:00:00 but its not selecting the value

Comment: How are `Pick_date` and `Pick_time` declared? Are they `varchar`, `date`...?

Comment: Pick_date datatype = date (yyyy-mm-dd) and Pick_time datatype = time(24 hours)

Comment: I set up the example on [rextester](http://rextester.com/TFL69429) and it's working fine. How is it different from your scenario?

Comment: i'm getting null result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142067/discussion-between-anjali-jibhakate-and-stefano-zanini).

Answer (score 1):

Try the Following:

```
Select * From ordermaster om
Where  Concat(om.Pick_date,' ', om.Pick_time) as date Between 
       (now() - interval 2 hour) and now()
       AND Status = 2
```

Comment: post syntax here please and let me see

Comment: i just pasted the same query as you suggested and run but it's throwing an error

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as pdate Between 
       (now() - interval 2 hour) and now())
       AND om.St' at line 2